# Ubuntu 18.04 Server uses only 2GB RAM even under high load

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-18.04

my Ubuntu 18.04 Server has 64GB RAM but when I check via htop it never uses more than 2 GB RAM. This also happens if I install Web Apps or if I create database dumps. I would expect my server to use more than 2GB of RAM in these cases.

I did set max_memory in php to 16GB. phpinfo() shows that this setting applies. But still - the server never uses more than 2 GB. How can I let my server use RAM?

I run php7.4 (fpm), mariadb, apache2.4 on that server. there are some wordpress installations and there is a moodle installation with hundreds of users on it.

Comment: are you seriously complaining that your server is too effective when it comes to using hardware resources efficiently? Besides, "unused" memory is used by the OS to cache your hard disk - which holds your database for example, which results in a faster access times!

Comment: I am relatively new to server administration. It just looks odd having a system that runs under heavy load and uses 2GB of RAM only. I was looking at it and thought: "If you just could use more RAM you might perform better/faster".

So then everyhing seems to be fine. But still - it feels odd. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: well, a few hundred users is not exactly a "heavy load" - you would have to add a few zeros to apply for heavy load. And, remember: the server just needs to copy the data from the database to the network connection - such a copy doesn't need that much memory. I'd recommend search for hardware requirements of a wordpress installation... you will see that it doesn't require much.

Comment: If your database is not that big, you might want to set up a database cache tmpfs for it, where you might use some of your unspent memory to decrease database latency.